# What are the cons and pros of different concurrent map implementations? When to use one or another?

Tags: scala, concurrency, scala-collections

Any suggestion on which concurrent map implementation to use in scala?

`java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap` or `scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap` or anything else?

Any performance comparison?
Thanks

Comment: I would bring `mutable.ParHashMap` and `immutable.ParHashMap` to the table.

Comment: Also consider an Akka agent wrapping an immutable `Map`.